# Master page controls in child pages?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am using master page and child pages. my requirement is can i access the master page controls in child page exmaple in my master page i have a linkbutton how can access in childpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Page.Master` property to access the masterpage.

```
LinkButton masterControl = Page.Master.FindControl("ControlID") as LinkButton;
```